# c# XML and LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML doc that looks like so:

```
<people>
  <person>
    <name>mike</name>
    <address>1 main st</address>
    <jobTitle>SE</jobTitme>
       <children>
           <name>mary</name>
           <age>5</age>
       </childres> 
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>john</name>
    <address>2 main st</address>
    <jobTitle>SE</jobTitme>
  </person>
</people>`
```

So not all of the person blocks and a children block.  Pretty simple.  When I add a new person to the XML via C#, I am writing a function that takes a person object and that person object has a collection of children objects (which may be 0 or more).  I am having trouble writing the linq in that function.  I can easily add a person object, but conditionally adding 1 or more children is tough. Here is what I have so far:

```
    doc.Element("People").Add(
            new XElement("Person", 
                new XElement("Name", person.name),
                new XElement("Address", person.address),
                new XElement("jobTitle", person.jobTitle)))
```

how can I conditionally add the children if they exist?

`public class person
    {
        public List<Child> childList;
        public string name;
        public string address;
        public string jobTitle
    }`

`public class child
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I conditionally add the children if they exist?

Three options:

- Use a `null` argument in the `XElement` call; that will be ignored
- Pass in an empty sequence of children; again, this will be irrelevant
- Build the rest of the element, then just conditionally call `Add` afterwards.

It's hard to give more concrete advice without seeing the code for your `Person` type.

(As an aside, it looks like your element should actually be `child` rather than children, assuming that you have one element per child...)

EDIT: Now that we can see your code, it looks like you just want:

```
doc.Element("People").Add(
        new XElement("Person", 
            new XElement("Name", person.name),
            new XElement("jobTitle", job.title),
            person.children.Select(c => new XElement("children",
                new XElement("Name", c.name),
                new XElement("Age", c.age)))));
```

Note that you're currently being very inconsistent with your capitalization when it comes to element names, and also it's a bad idea to expose public fields like this.

Comment: Can you show an example of one of them?  The classes involved and as simple as they get, public string members or the child and person class.

Comment: @user1048323: Your comment is unclear, but please include the relevant classes in your question. In particular, as "children" is plural I'd expect some sort of *collection* of children as a property of Person, but you haven't explained what's available.

Comment: 'public class Person { public List<Child> childList; public string name; public string address; public string jobTitle; }

Comment: public class child{ public string name; public int age; }

Comment: @user1048323: As I said before, please edit the code into your *question*. (Also, I'd avoid using public fields if I were you...)

Comment: I am changing the class names to protect confidentiality, I am just trying to get the idea across.  So if I have a function which gets passed a person object, with the possibility of multiple child objects, the code you added would update the XML accordingly?  I'm obviously just learning linq syntax.

Comment: I would think I would need something with a loop to add the children.

Comment: @user1048323: Nope - if you provide LINQ to XML with a sequence, it will add all of them. The code in my answer should work fine.